# rewriterule for apache tomcat

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

I have installed apache tomcat software for learning jsp.
In that software how to do that all request can handle from one class or file,
In WAMP, we can do with rewriterule, but in apache tomcat how to do, can anybody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can use a `Filter` for that purposes. Since it could require some job, you can use library for that like [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) if you don't want to complicate your project.

Also, if you are learning JSP, I suggest you to learn JSF 2.X instead since JSP is deprecated. In that case, you will probably like to use [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/).